# What's a good way to keep a bluetooth connection alive and available?

Tags: sockets, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-socket

What I've tried so far is to close the socket and open a new one every 15 seconds. Is that reliable?

Trying to keep a connection with a bluetooth printer

Comment: In what way does closing a socket constitute keeping it alive?

Comment: @EJP that's a good point, I've edited the title.